# Menu de Seleção de países

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Existe algum componente presente no Bootstrap 3.3.1 (Creio que não) que gere um select de todos os paises? ou algum plugin? pois atualmente estou usando uma lista com HTML puro que esta gigantesca, abaixo uma pequena parte do codigo que quero substituir:

```
<select name="paises" id="paises">
   <option value="Brasil" selected="selected">Brasil</option>
   <option value="Afeganistão">Afeganistão</option>
   <option value="África do Sul">África do Sul</option>
   <option value="Albânia">Albânia</option>
</select>
```

Outro problema seria internacionalizar toda a lista

Comment: Você pode também criar um JSON com a lista dos países e popular o `<select>` via AJAX, previne retrabalho e um HTML gigante, além de ser mais performático.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontrei um repositório no Github com o que procuras: https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list. [Existem outros pelos vistos](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AFAB_svSE483SE483&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=json%20country%20list).

As linguas disponíveis são:

```
["aa","aa_DJ","aa_ER","aa_ET","af","af_NA","af_ZA","ak","ak_GH","am","am_ET","ar","ar_AE","ar_BH","ar_DZ","ar_EG","ar_IQ","ar_JO","ar_KW","ar_LB","ar_LY","ar_MA","ar_OM","ar_QA","ar_SA","ar_SD","ar_SY","ar_TN","ar_YE","as","as_IN","asa","asa_TZ","az","az_AZ","az_Arab","az_Arab_IR","az_Cyrl","az_Cyrl_AZ","az_IR","az_Latn","az_Latn_AZ","be","be_BY","bem","bem_ZM","bez","bez_TZ","bg","bg_BG","bm","bm_ML","bn","bn_BD","bn_IN","bo","bo_CN","bo_IN","br","br_FR","brx","brx_IN","bs","bs_BA","byn","byn_ER","ca","ca_ES","cch","cch_NG","cgg","cgg_UG","chr","chr_US","cs","cs_CZ","cy","cy_GB","da","da_DK","dav","dav_KE","de","de_AT","de_BE","de_CH","de_DE","de_LI","de_LU","dv","dv_MV","dz","dz_BT","ebu","ebu_KE","ee","ee_GH","ee_TG","el","el_CY","el_GR","el_POLYTON","en","en_AS","en_AU","en_BE","en_BW","en_BZ","en_CA","en_Dsrt","en_Dsrt_US","en_GB","en_GU","en_HK","en_IE","en_IN","en_JM","en_MH","en_MP","en_MT","en_MU","en_NA","en_NZ","en_PH","en_PK","en_SG","en_Shaw","en_TT","en_UM","en_US","en_US_POSIX","en_VI","en_ZA","en_ZW","en_ZZ","eo","es","es_419","es_AR","es_BO","es_CL","es_CO","es_CR","es_DO","es_EC","es_ES","es_GQ","es_GT","es_HN","es_MX","es_NI","es_PA","es_PE","es_PR","es_PY","es_SV","es_US","es_UY","es_VE","et","et_EE","eu","eu_ES","fa","fa_AF","fa_IR","ff","ff_SN","fi","fi_FI","fil","fil_PH","fo","fo_FO","fr","fr_BE","fr_BF","fr_BI","fr_BJ","fr_BL","fr_CA","fr_CD","fr_CF","fr_CG","fr_CH","fr_CI","fr_CM","fr_DJ","fr_FR","fr_GA","fr_GN","fr_GP","fr_GQ","fr_KM","fr_LU","fr_MC","fr_MF","fr_MG","fr_ML","fr_MQ","fr_NE","fr_RE","fr_RW","fr_SN","fr_TD","fr_TG","fur","fur_IT","ga","ga_IE","gaa","gaa_GH","gez","gez_ER","gez_ET","gl","gl_ES","gsw","gsw_CH","gu","gu_IN","guz","guz_KE","gv","gv_GB","ha","ha_Arab","ha_Arab_NG","ha_Arab_SD","ha_GH","ha_Latn","ha_Latn_GH","ha_Latn_NE","ha_Latn_NG","ha_NE","ha_NG","ha_SD","haw","haw_US","he","he_IL","hi","hi_IN","hr","hr_HR","hu","hu_HU","hy","hy_AM","ia","id","id_ID","ig","ig_NG","ii","ii_CN","in","is","is_IS","it","it_CH","it_IT","iu","iw","ja","ja_JP","jmc","jmc_TZ","ka","ka_GE","kab","kab_DZ","kaj","kaj_NG","kam","kam_KE","kcg","kcg_NG","kde","kde_TZ","kea","kea_CV","kfo","kfo_CI","khq","khq_ML","ki","ki_KE","kk","kk_Cyrl","kk_Cyrl_KZ","kk_KZ","kl","kl_GL","kln","kln_KE","km","km_KH","kn","kn_IN","ko","ko_KR","kok","kok_IN","kpe","kpe_GN","kpe_LR","ksb","ksb_TZ","ksh","ksh_DE","ku","ku_Arab","ku_Arab_IQ","ku_Arab_IR","ku_IQ","ku_IR","ku_Latn","ku_Latn_SY","ku_Latn_TR","ku_SY","ku_TR","kw","kw_GB","ky","ky_KG","lag","lag_TZ","lg","lg_UG","ln","ln_CD","ln_CG","lo","lo_LA","lt","lt_LT","luo","luo_KE","luy","luy_KE","lv","lv_LV","mas","mas_KE","mas_TZ","mer","mer_KE","mfe","mfe_MU","mg","mg_MG","mi","mi_NZ","mk","mk_MK","ml","ml_IN","mn","mn_CN","mn_Cyrl","mn_Cyrl_MN","mn_MN","mn_Mong","mn_Mong_CN","mo","mr","mr_IN","ms","ms_BN","ms_MY","mt","mt_MT","my","my_MM","naq","naq_NA","nb","nb_NO","nd","nd_ZW","nds","nds_DE","ne","ne_IN","ne_NP","nl","nl_BE","nl_NL","nn","nn_NO","no","nr","nr_ZA","nso","nso_ZA","ny","ny_MW","nyn","nyn_UG","oc","oc_FR","om","om_ET","om_KE","or","or_IN","pa","pa_Arab","pa_Arab_PK","pa_Guru","pa_Guru_IN","pa_IN","pa_PK","pl","pl_PL","ps","ps_AF","pt","pt_AO","pt_BR","pt_GW","pt_MZ","pt_PT","rm","rm_CH","ro","ro_MD","ro_RO","rof","rof_TZ","ru","ru_MD","ru_RU","ru_UA","rw","rw_RW","rwk","rwk_TZ","sa","sa_IN","saq","saq_KE","se","se_FI","se_NO","seh","seh_MZ","ses","ses_ML","sg","sg_CF","sh","sh_BA","sh_CS","sh_YU","shi","shi_Latn","shi_Latn_MA","shi_MA","shi_Tfng","shi_Tfng_MA","si","si_LK","sid","sid_ET","sk","sk_SK","sl","sl_SI","sn","sn_ZW","so","so_DJ","so_ET","so_KE","so_SO","sq","sq_AL","sr","sr_BA","sr_CS","sr_Cyrl","sr_Cyrl_BA","sr_Cyrl_CS","sr_Cyrl_ME","sr_Cyrl_RS","sr_Cyrl_YU","sr_Latn","sr_Latn_BA","sr_Latn_CS","sr_Latn_ME","sr_Latn_RS","sr_Latn_YU","sr_ME","sr_RS","sr_YU","ss","ss_SZ","ss_ZA","ssy","ssy_ER","st","st_LS","st_ZA","sv","sv_FI","sv_SE","sw","sw_KE","sw_TZ","syr","syr_SY","ta","ta_IN","ta_LK","te","te_IN","teo","teo_KE","teo_UG","tg","tg_Cyrl","tg_Cyrl_TJ","tg_TJ","th","th_TH","ti","ti_ER","ti_ET","tig","tig_ER","tl","tl_PH","tn","tn_ZA","to","to_TO","tr","tr_TR","trv","trv_TW","ts","ts_ZA","tt","tt_RU","tzm","tzm_Latn","tzm_Latn_MA","tzm_MA","ug","ug_Arab","ug_Arab_CN","ug_CN","uk","uk_UA","ur","ur_IN","ur_PK","uz","uz_AF","uz_Arab","uz_Arab_AF","uz_Cyrl","uz_Cyrl_UZ","uz_Latn","uz_Latn_UZ","uz_UZ","ve","ve_ZA","vi","vi_VN","vun","vun_TZ","wal","wal_ET","wo","wo_Latn","wo_Latn_SN","wo_SN","xh","xh_ZA","xog","xog_UG","yo","yo_NG","zh","zh_CN","zh_HK","zh_Hans","zh_Hans_CN","zh_Hans_HK","zh_Hans_MO","zh_Hans_SG","zh_Hant","zh_Hant_HK","zh_Hant_MO","zh_Hant_TW","zh_MO","zh_SG","zh_TW","zu","zu_ZA"]
```

Nem todas as linguas têm os países todos, mas podes selecionar só as que vais usar mais vezes. Senão vais ter de completar ou procurar mais, ou pagar algum serviço para te dar uma lista completa.

Para usares isto precisas de ir buscar ao GitHub consoante a lingua, ou fazes uma cópia no teu servidor que é mais seguro.

Aqui fica um exemplo de como fazer com jQuery usando esse repositório do GitHub.

### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pru0zw6j/

O código relevante é:

HTML

```
<select name="lingua" id="linguas"></select>
<select name="paises" id="paises"></select>
```

JS

```
var linguas = ["aa", "aa_DJ", "aa_ER", "aa_ET", etc.... // a array que coloquei em cima
var select_linguas = $('#linguas');
linguas.forEach(function (lingua) {
    select_linguas.append('<option value="' + lingua + '">' + lingua + '</option>');
});

select_linguas.on('change', function () {
    var lingua = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://rawgit.com/umpirsky/country-list/master/country/cldr/" + lingua + "/country.json",           
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        var novosPaises = Object.keys(data).map(function (lingua) {
            return '<option value="' + lingua + '">' + data[lingua] + '</option>';
        });
        $('#paises').html(novosPaises);
    });
});
```

## Para usares no teu próprio servidor:

(a opção mais segura) podes fazer assim:

Copia os ficheiros para o servidor e cria um ficheiro PHP para ler o JSON. Um exemplo simples:

le_json.php

```
$json_file = file_get_contents('country.json');
echo $json_file;
```

index.php

```
$.ajax({
        url:"le_json.php",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (dados) {
    console.log(typeof dados)
         for (codigo in dados){
        $('body').append('<div>' + dados[codigo] + ', ' + codigo + '</div>'); 
    }; 
});
```

Desta maneira funciona até no velhinho IE8.
Exemplo que criei num servidor onlline: http://goo.gl/JlvpF3

Comment: Olá @sergio, haveria alguma forma de obter via .json? outra coisa $.ajax eu necessitaria de um webserver para utilizar(xampp, wampp)?

Comment: @RicardoHenrique o exemplo qe dei vai buscar um JSON. A solução que dei é com JSON. Em relação ao `$.ajax` não precisa de webserver, funciona localmente, é JavaScript...

Comment: verificando outras soluções que não precisariam de webserver (ainda não tinha lido seu comentario) me deparei com o seguinte codigo: $.getJSON(url_do_json, function(dados) {
    for(var i=0; i<dados.length; i++) {
        $(document.body).append('<div>' + dados[i].titulo + ', ' + dados[i].duracao + '</div>');
    }
});
testei ele dentro de $(document).ready(function() porem o mesmo não funcionou o que poço fazer para fazer funcionar?

Comment: @RicardoHenrique esse `$.getJSON` é na prática o mesmo que o meu código O meu código com `$.getJSON` fica assim: http://jsfiddle.net/pru0zw6j/1/

Comment: é possivel usar um .json armazenado na minha propria maquina?

Comment: @RicardoHenrique sim é. Podes copiar o repositório do GitHub e usar no dominio local.

Comment: Ok, estou usando o documento json fornecido por eles, outro ponto, teste usando somente este json (sem a var com o conteudo) com o seguinte codigo $.getJSON("../HTML/Countries.json", function(dados) {
   alert(dados.length);
   for(var i=0; i<dados.length; i++) {
    //$(document.body).append('<div>' + dados[i].name + ', ' + dados[i].code + '</div>');
    alert(dados[i].name);
   }
  });
porem não funcionou

Answer (score -3):

Não sei se você gostaria ou está a utilizar react js, mas há uma maneira de fazer isso utilizando uma API do IBGE. Ela disponibiliza para você tanto nomes de países, como de UF e cidades. Segue abaixo o código caso se interesse:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select';
//aqui acima voce importa os hooks 

const Register = () => {
    //cria seu useState para setar o valor da sua variável
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      //aqui tu puxa o link da API que contém os países
       fetch('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/paises')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                const options = data.map(country => {
                    return {
                        value: country.id,
                        label: country.nome
                    };
                });
                setCountries(options);
            });
    }, []);
    
    // dentro do teu jsx tu faz o seguinte
     <label>
         <Select options={countries} id='select' />
     </label>
```