# criar combobox dinamico em javascript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como faço para ter quatro combobox, no qual o primeiro seria as opções de estados, e após selecionado o estado o segundo combobox carregaria automaticamente os municípios pertencentes.

Comment: Posso estar enganado mas acho que já existem várias perguntas e respostas sobre o assunto aqui no StackOverflow. Acho que está querendo saber como atualizar o elemento com `ajax`.

Comment: obrigado Renan, irei dar uma melhor procurada

Comment: existe ainda outra pergunta relavcionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45090/129. Se ainda tiveres problemas comenta aqui. Bemvindo ao Stackoverflow!